# how do i access lists values stored in a dictionary key?

Tags: python

I have got a dictionary of lists. Lets say it looks like this :

```
dictionary1 = {
    'key1':[10000,20000],
    'key2':[30000,40000],
    'key3':[50000,60000],
    # and so on...
}
```

I want to access these two values from each key and use it with `sys.argv`

It should work like this :

`python command key1`

to get values 10000 and 20000 from key1 and use it in a `for loop`

and

`python command key2`

to get 30000 and 40000 from key2 and use it in the same `for loop`

How do access these two list values from each key ?

Comment: don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: By "lower and upper values", do you mean the first and last items in the list, or the items which have the least and greatest values?

Comment: @Aya
lower-value-1 = 10 upper-value-2 = 20
lower-value-3 = 21 upper-value-4 = 30
lower-value-5 = 31 upper-value-6 = 40
and so on...
These are just small values i am actually using values in thousands.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary it was just an example to represent a dictionary.

Comment: @madil That doesn't really answer my question. If none of the current answers is correct, perhaps you should change the code sample in the original question so it's more like what you're actually using.

Comment: @Aya see if you could help me now.

Comment: @madil Well, @Antimony's solution will grab the values, you just need to use them in a call to the `range()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which part are you confused about? can't you just do

```
lower, upper = dictionary1[key]
```

Comment: don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: getting lower and upper values from each key.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : i am not using dict as a variable name. this was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the buit-in `min` and `max` functions:

```
the_key = 'key1'
lower_value, upper_value = min(the_dict[the_key]), max(the_dict[the_key])
```

Also, as a general rule - do not name your variables with the same name as a built-in. This is called "shadowing". `dict` is a built-in, which is why I changed the name to `the_dict` in my example.

Comment: using `dict` was just for illustration purpose only. I have other variable names in my program.